# EDAC bridge lost 6000+ errors

Tags: memory, centos

I've setup two new servers for virtualization, and after working with them for a few hours i noticed a lot of error messages, starting at boot I get an error saying `EDAC sbridge: lost 150 memory errors, after a few minutes it gets to 6000 and rising.
Checking /var/log/messages I see that all errors are CE, meaning that they have been corrected.
But it is normal? that many errors?

OS is Centos 7 X64
Total amount of RAM is 128 GB, Samsung ECC 16G X8.
Motherboard is asus x99-ws/ipmi
CPU is Intel Xeon E5-2699 V3

I've tried swaping the RAM with new out of the box sticks and still the same.

Comment: It is not normal... High CE is often a sign of failing hardware. Usually the RAM but possibly the MC or a misconfiguration. Have you examined the /sys/devices/system/edac/mc directory structure to see what memory controller and CS row (DIMM bank) is correcting the errors? This might give you some insight https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/edac.txt

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was the power supply, after switching to a different brand all error messages stopped. 
Another issue I didn't notice was that only 6 if the 8 ram sticks were identified, this was also fixed with a new PSU.

Comment: Although this solved the problem, it doesn't answer the questions "Checking /var/log/messages I see that all errors are CE, meaning that they have been corrected. But it is normal? that many errors?"